# Minify css using Gulp

Tags: gulp

I want only "app.scss" in minified version, right now I am getting all three SCSS file converted into ".min" files. Please help

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename')

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(['scss/style.scss', 'scss/variable.scss', 'scss/app.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'compressed'}))
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
```

Comment: Do any of the answers fix your query?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently piping all three files to the same `sass` pipe with the same `compressed` setting. There are various options to fix this, including:

- use [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) to selectively do compressed an non-compressed calls to `sass`
- create different streams and use [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) to return them as one merged result from your task

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you are running all your commands on a single source blob. This causes all operations to perform on the same set of files. What you need is the output of one command into another. This is also the correct way to do it, by writing an individual `task` for each operation.

Use a [sequence plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence) to perform the tasks one after another and use another `gulp.src` to get the combined file. Something like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    // Compile Sass
    return gulp.src(['scss/style.scss', 'scss/variable.scss', 'scss/app.scss'])
    ... bla bla ...

});

gulp.task('minify', function(){
    // Minify
    return gulp.src(['app.scss'])
    ... bla bla ...
});

gulp.task('all', function(cb){
    gulpSequence(['sass', 'minify'], cb);
});
```